# Force ClearType text rendering in a popup

Tags: wpf, cleartype

I know that WPF disables ClearType text rendering if it is in doubt whether the background is fully opaque. There's the `RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint` attached property that can be used to assure WPF that it's safe to use ClearType rendering in a certain subtree. This is what I used on my popup with an opaque background and a shadow around it. But it has no effect. The text always shows up with greyscale smoothing.

I tried the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.cleartypehint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of this property, and its example in Kaxaml. They say the third text should use ClearType but may show wrong rendering. But it's wrong! The third text is also just greyscale.

Also when inspecting the default control template for a ComboBox popup, they don't do anything else but it works fine in their control. I want the same rendering performance in my customised popup control.

Is there a way to definitely, finally force WPF to use ClearType text rendering in some place? I don't like its stupid smartness that prevents the right things from happening because they might be unsafe (but really are not).